# VueJs3 Fresh install TypeScript Error Option 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is deprecated

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

```
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

On the first brace, I get this error :

> Option 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is deprecated and will stop functioning in TypeScript 5.5. Specify compilerOption '"ignoreDeprecations": "5.0"' to silence this error.
> Use 'verbatimModuleSyntax' instead.

Do you know how I can fix this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error comes from this line (first code section), because this file isn't compatible anymore with `Typescript 5.0`, `createVue` still didn't have upgrade his dependencies to `@vue/tsconfig` to support `Typescript 5.0`:

```
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
```

It imports the file `tsconfig.web.json` which contains `importsNotUsedAsValues`.

To fix the error, you can install `@vue/tsconfig` as an independent module to have the last version which support `Typescript 5.0` :

```
npm remove @vue/tsconfig.json
npm i @vue/tsconfig
```

Then you can change in your tsconfig.json :

```
"extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
```

Normally, the file doesn't contain `importsNotUsedAsValues` anymore.

[Official tsconfig which support ts5](https://github.com/vuejs/tsconfig/blob/main/tsconfig.json)
[NPM reference for @vue/tsconfig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/tsconfig)

You can still just wait for `createVue` or whatever you used to create your project to upgrade his dependencies to support `Typescript 5.0` but here is why you get the error and how at the present moment you can get rid of it + you would have to recreate it.